# A good and maintainable way to generate SQLite 3 database from MySQL one?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have to generate on-the-fly (and let the user download) an SQLite 3 encrypted database, starting/cloning part of the current running MySQL database.

I need to export only a subset of the tables (i.e. products, categories, users), and I'd like to make the procedure dynamic, meaning that adding a field in MySQL shouldn't require changes in the procedure.

I need to some high-level "tips" to make the procedure as robust as possible.

Questions: how do I map column types in MySQL to SQLite types? How can I fetch metadata to determine the correct INSERT statements order? Should I need to lock MySQL database while dumping it into SQLite?

```
<?php

$sqlite = new PDO('sqlite::memory:', null, null, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
]);

$mysql = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=database', 'root', 'root', [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
]);

// Enable foreign keys in SQLite
$sqlite->exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1');

// 1) Getting meta information from MySQL

// 2) CREATE TABLE ... in the SQLite schema, dynamically

// 3) INSERT INTO ... statements of SQLite (in the correct order)

// 4) Save the in-memory database to filesystem and send it to the browser
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin allows you to export a database in multiple formats (not SQLite though it does ANSI). You might take a look at how they do it.